# Merlin is not picking up dependencies in a nix flake shell

Tags: nix, ocamlfind, merlin, nix-flake

I have a flake containing a dev shell pinning all the dependencies required to develop a given OCaml program, including an actual OCaml compiler, merlin, findlib and the OCaml libraries. For instance, if the project only depended on `Graphics`, it could be:

```hs
devShell = pkgs.mkShell {
    buildInputs = with pkgs; [
        ocaml
    ] ++ (with ocamlPackages; [
        findlib
        merlin
        graphics
    ]);
};
```

In addition to that, I have direnv setup to use the flake with the following in `.envrc`:

```bash
use flake
```

And it works fine. If I even add `dune` (to help finding out where the libraries out) and `utop`, like

```hs
buildInputs = with pkgs; [
    ocaml
    dune_3
] ++ (with ocamlPackages; [
    findlib
    merlin
    graphics
    utop
]);
```

I can run `dune utop`, then `# open Graphics;;` and it still works. After setting up a minimal dune project, `dune build` just works.

Direnv is also setup for Emacs, so when I edit an OCaml file `merlin-mode` picks up the shell's merlin flawlessly. Similarly for the shell's utop. But if I  add `open Graphics`, it says "Unbound module Graphics", as if merlin couldn't pick up the dependency.

I've tried following [this article](https://blog.jethro.dev/posts/ocaml_emacs_nixos/), which essentially adds `${merlin}/share/emacs/site-lisp` to the `load-path` in Emacs. But that didn't work.

I've also tried moving to `ocaml-lsp`+`lsp-mode` instead of `merlin`, but that didn't help.

I found [this post](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/non-opam-workflows/5232) that describes someone achieving Emacs' integration, but it provided no details on how to achieve that besides configuring `ocamlformat`, but since it's not in my minimal reproducible example, I don't think it's pertinent.